# How to add a wsl directory to windows path?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wsl-2

I want to add this directory in my WSL to the windows Path to work with python selenium as a web driver path.

`directory="~/projects/health_index/insurance_score"`

How can I do this?

Comment: @Alexander But when I give this directory as a path for ```executable_path``` variable in wsl, selenium gives this error: "WebDriverException: Message: 'insurance_score' executable needs to be in PATH."

Comment: Used import pathlib.

Answer (score 0):

we cannot add a wsl directory to windows path.
the reason of my problem with selenium was working in wsl. i made an env in windows and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: can you add more details about how you solved your problem, please?

Comment: the problem was solved by creating a new env in windows and using windows path.